# Removing index.php from URL in CodeIgniter using .htaccess file, still getting error "index.php not found"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have  done all three steps to remove `index.php` from my URL, but when I run it, it gives me this error:

> Not Found
>   The requested URL /ci_test/index.php was not found on this server.

I did these 3 steps:

1. application/config/config.php

   ```
   $config['index_page'] = '';
   $config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
   ```
2. Add .htaccess file
3. Enabled Rewrite mode in Apache server

Comment: what about your .htaccess code?

Comment: @shilpa re edit your question with htaccess not good to put in comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your `.htaccess` file in root directory with following.working for me..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci_test/';

$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Comment: @shilpa lets cheers and enjoy with codeigniter..have a nice ahead

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /ci_test/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```